# how to convert pd.to_datetime to JSON by sort_values function in pandas dataframe?

Tags: json, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe containing datetime objects when i sort the values using sort_values it comes into proper dateformat but further when i convert into JSON it comes with some orther format **`Date":1404777600000`**
i have used **`pd.to_datetime()`** for conversion

```
bot5 = data.sort_values('Amount',ascending=True)[['Time','Region','Amount','Class']].tail(N).reset_index() 
print(bot5.to_json(orient='records'))
```

> [{"Date":1404777600000,"Amount":25691.16,"Region":"south"},{"Date":1418083200000,"Amount":19656.53,"Region":"south"},

Comment: Format your code properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From pandas documentation:

> Type of date conversion. epoch = epoch milliseconds, iso = ISO8601. The default depends on the orient. For orient=’table’, the default is ‘iso’. For all other orients, the default is ‘epoch’.

You are using `records` orient, so, by default, pandas converting your dates to epoch dates. You can change type of date conversion to `iso`, by passing argument `date_format='iso'`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [2015, 2016],
    'month': [2, 3],
    'day': [4, 5], 
    'Amount': [25691.16, 19656.53], 
    'Region': ['south', 'south']
})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day']])
(df[['Date', 'Amount', 'Region']]
    .sort_values('Amount', ascending=True)
    .to_json(orient='records', date_format='iso', date_unit='ns'))
# '[{"Date":"2016-03-05T00:00:00.000000000Z","Amount":19656.53,"Region":"south"},
#   {"Date":"2015-02-04T00:00:00.000000000Z","Amount":25691.16,"Region":"south"}]'
```

One more catch, `to_datetime` converts with nanosecond resolution, by default, but `to_json` saves dates with `ms` resolution, by default, so you need to pass correct `date_unit` argument(`date_unit='ns'`) too.

Comment: how to get date in date.format='iso' {"Date":"2016-03-05T00:00:00.000000000Z"} is there is any method for that ?

Comment: @sujithradeepak You mean, you want only date part in generated json? Like `2016-03-05` instead of `2016-03-05T00:00:00.000000000Z`?

Comment: yes i want to generate only date part in generated json through date.format='iso' is there any way for that?

Comment: @sujithradeepak If it's ok, if `Date` column in your dataframe will be of type `str`, then you can do `df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))` and then, call `to_json` with only `orient` argument, like `to_json(orient='records')`. Or you can create new column, like `Date_str`. Unfortunately, you can't specify alternative date format through `to_json` arguments.